# Reactjs ; destructuring props assignment with ESLint rules

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

using ESLing plugin for react I got confused in destructuring and prop types validation.
in class like below

```
class Game extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.createNewPlayer(); //  Must use destructuring props assignment (react/destructuring-assignment)
  }

  render() {
    const { players } = this.props; // 'players' is missing in props validation (react/prop-types)
    const count = Object.keys(players).length;
    return (...);
  }
}

GameInit.propTypes = {createNewPlayer: PropTypes.func.isRequired};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({players: state.players});

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{ createNewPlayer })(Game);
```

so if I re-write destructure of the first part to

```
  componentWillMount() {
    const {createNewPlayer}=this.props; // 'createNewPlayer' is already declared in the upper scope. (no-shadow) 
    createNewPlayer();
  }
```

and for destructure of player if I re-write proptypes as

```
GameInit.propTypes = {
  createNewPlayer: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  players: PropTypes.object.isRequired, // Prop type `object` is forbidden (react/forbid-prop-types)
};
```

what is the correct way of following ESLint rules here? without changing the rules in `.eslintrc`

Comment: Also disabling by line works for complicated objects.  // eslint-disable-line [rule name]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably this will solve your first problem:

```
const {createNewPlayer: createNewPlayerAlt } = this.props;
createNewPlayerAlt();
```

For the second part, you should specify what kind of object you have here.

Objects that all the properties are a string:

```
players: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.String)
```

Objects that all the properties are a number:

```
players: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.Number)
```

Do you have mixed properties? Then go with `shape`:

```
player: PropTypes.shape({
    id: PropTypes.string,
    playerNumber: PropTypes.number
  }),
```

Comment: Thanks, haha my player model is complicated, so it's better to ignore it at rules.

Comment: Prop types are good when there is a problem with your data. But for complex objects, yeah it is a pain in somewhere :) One or two is not a problem but when your app gets bigger, it is really hard to be patient about writing all of them.